# Terminating connection TCP

Tags: sockets, http, tcp

I'm trying to understand some of the fundamentals about TCP/networking.

Let's say I have client sending an HTTP request to server to download a large file over a fast connection.

```
curl http://downloadfile > file
```

The server writes the huge file on a socket. If the server crashes/dies, is it all possible for the client to continue to receive the file even though the server just died?

In other words, how does the client know the connection has been terminated before it finishes getting data on the socket?

I'm guess that it would time out once no new data is on the socket, but is it possible for the entire file to be transmitted onto the socket before the client receives all the data?

Answer (score 0):

> is it all possible for the client to continue to receive the file even though the server just died?

Of course not. It can read whatever is in its socket receive buffer and whatever data was in flight, and that's it.

> In other words, how does the client know the connection has been terminated before it finishes getting data on the socket?

It may not know. It may just sit there in `read()` forever. Unless it has a read timeout.

> I'm guess that it would time out once no new data is on the socket

If and only if the client has set a read timeout.

> but is it possible for the entire file to be transmitted onto the socket before the client receives all the data?

There is the server. There is the server's socket send buffer. If the server has crashed, both are out of contention. There is the client's socket receive buffer, but that's logically part of the client: it holds data that has arrived that hasn't been read by the application yet. It is finite in size.

Comment: So I have a connection to between a client and a server, and I shut down the server and the file the client is downloading continues to download for a few minutes more - what would be the explanation for that? that the client socket receive buffer still has data in it that hasn't been read by the application yet?